# Bluemix dev-ops services Web API?

Tags: ibm-cloud, continuous-delivery, devops-services

I thought I'd read that there was an entire web services API for automating the latest Bluemix DevOps tooling? I don't see anything obvious in the documentation

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/ContinuousDelivery/index.html#cd_getting_started

Comment: We're currently working on the API documentation for both toolchain templates and tool integrations, so it's definitely coming. What particular areas are most interested in?

Comment: Well, my personal goal is always to automate every click and typing of text as it relates to pipelines. For example, in Jenkins scripted pipelines are a great new feature that can be checked-in as files to SCM. Sometimes, it's just as simple as having a shell script to automate the creation (definition) of a new pipeline.

(i.e. Automation - everywhere)

Answer (score 1):

You're right. You can choose to create a toolchain or start from a toolchain template. 
You may find this microservices devops toolchain template tutorial helpful.
https://www.ibm.com/devops/method/tutorials/tutorial_toolchain_microservices_cd?task=1

By default, the toolchain comes with these tool integrations:

- IBM-hosted Git Repos and Issue Tracking repositories (repos)
- Delivery pipelines
- IBM Cloud DevOps Insights
- The Eclipse Orion Web IDE
- Sauce Labs
- pagerDuty
- Slack

Comment: This isn't an API. There are no automation service endpoints to this. The tutorial refers to "Click" in many places (i.e. manual setup). Templates help expedite setup, but there's still a person clicking on things in the portal. An example goal is to run a script to create a new DevOps pipeline (e.g. a single microservice pipeline), delete it and re-run the script and have the pipeline back. Same goes for configuring tool integrations. Every configuration should have an associated API service call.

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/open-toolchain/sdk/wiki

This is where we are defining the API. Since SO won't let us have a conversation about what you're actual requirements are, feel free to create an issue on the repo to capture them.

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding some details as to `how/which API lets you automate the latest Bluemix DevOps tooling`

Comment: @McQ a quick review doesn't show me any web services I can call. The link seems to be just the documentation for templates.